# Distribute value based on another dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to distribute the Profit based on another dataframe

DF1:

```
Item    From    Price    Discount   
 A     Delhi    100        .10      
 A     Mumbai   200        .10    
 A     Pune     150        .10     
 A     Nagpur   200        .10
```

DF2:

```
Item      From     To
 A        Delhi    Mumbai
 A        Mumbai   Pune
 A        Mumbai   Nagpur
```

Profit is calculated as Price*Discount

Here, In DF1 we are calculating the profit and based on the relationship in DF2 we need to add it in the price of connected city. We calculated profit for Delhi and it is only connected to Mumbai so transfer the profit to the price of Mumbai.

But when we calculated the profit for Mumbai it is connected to Pune and Nagpur so the profit need to be divided and added to the price of Pune & Nagpur

Can someone help me to write a for loop for this.

Output:

```
Item    From    Price    Discount    Profit
 A     Delhi    100        .10         10
 A     Mumbai   200+10     .10         21
 A     Pune     150+10.5   .10         16
 A     Nagpur   200+10.5   .10         21
```

Comment: Not clear. Can you add some more information? How is the profit calculated?

Comment: Profit is calculated as Price*Discount

Comment: @RonakShah 210 * 0.1 and 160.5 * 0.1

Comment: In Mumbai, 10 came from profit of Delhi bcz in DF2 Delhi is only connected to Mumbai. 
But as Mumbai is connected to Pune and Nagpur so it's profit got distributed to the price of Pune & Nagpur

Comment: @RonakShah from previous entry given that it is connected (df2). So If you see the previous entry is 21. Because Mumbai is connected to two cities, then those cities split the profit (i.e. 21) to 10.5 and 10.5

Comment: You need to play with lag and merge etc... I don't have time though to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `for` loop. Thanks to @Sotos and OP for detailed explanation.

```
#Initialize Profit column to 0
df1$Profit <- 0

for (i in seq_len(nrow(df1))) {
   #Check cities which are present in df2
   cities <- df2$To[df1$Item[i] == df2$Item & df1$From[i] == df2$From]
   inds <- df1$From %in% cities
   #Update the Price for matched cities
   if (any(inds))
     df1$Price[inds] <- df1$Price[inds] + 
                       (df1$Price[i] * df1$Discount[i]/length(cities))
   #Calculate Profit
   df1$Profit[i] <- df1$Price[i] * df1$Discount[i]
}

df1
#  Item   From Price Discount Profit
#1    A  Delhi 100.0      0.1  10.00
#2    A Mumbai 210.0      0.1  21.00
#3    A   Pune 160.5      0.1  16.05
#4    A Nagpur 210.5      0.1  21.05
```

Comment: Here we have divided by length(cities) as we need to divide it equally.
If we want to divide the profit of Mumbai by 60% to Pune and 40% to Nagpur. Can we do it?

Comment: @AnshulS yes, Maybe you can add a column in `df2` indicating what % of profit goes to which city and then use that to calculate Profit.

Comment: Thanks
I would like to divide it in the ratio of the Price of Pune & Nagpur

Comment: Thanks
I would like to divide it in the ratio of the Price of Pune & Nagpur. Pune here is 150/350 = .428 and for Napur 200/350 =  .571